# How to implement routing with id correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to route with an Id between the pages. I do so with `[routerLink]`. But when I run the app I get an error:  `Error: Cannot find module '../friend/friend-details.module'`. I suppose that I didn't type in correctly the path but I wouldn't know what I could try further. So I want to navigate to friend-details and pass on the id so it know which item it was. The friend-details folder is in the friend folder, so the path should actually work.

page.html

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let friend of loadedFriends">
 <ion-avatar  [routerLink]="['/', 'tabs', 'friend', friend.id]" slot="start">
</ion-card>
```

tabs.router.module.ts

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,  //render component that holds your tabs
        children: [
           {
        path: 'friend',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../friend/friend.module#FriendPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: ':friendId',
            loadChildren: '../friend/friend-details.module#FriendDetailsPageModule'  //maybe delete the same page of app.module.ts
          },
        ]
      },
```

EDIT:

I tried a solution in which I used a click event:

```
openFriendDetails() {
    this.router.navigate(['friend/:id']);
  }
```

which I take access from app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'friend/:id', loadChildren: './friend-details/friend-details.module#FriendDetailsPageModule' },
```

The navigation works after this change. But somehow I can't make use of my id since the friend-details page is frozen somehow and I can't change my page anymore.

Comment: does the error happen only when clicking? [here](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-routing-navigation/) is a good example to follow that will also show you passing through params.

Comment: yes only when clicking

Answer (score 0):

check your `friend-details module` path and put `id` as second router link param. for example : `[routerLink]="['/tabs/friend', friend.id]"` this will generate the route `/tabs/friend/:friendId` and you can access by `ActivatedRoute.params.friendId` into your component

Comment: if I change my route like that I get the error:  `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment' . But the other error disappears and in my console I see that the id changes correctly if I choose different elements. With this file above of my routing.module.ts the url should be correct?!

Answer (score 0):

first you need to change your `children` to this

```
children: [
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            loadChildren: '../friend/friend.module#FriendPageModule'
          },
          {
            path: ':friendId',
            loadChildren: '../friend/friend-details.module#FriendDetailsPageModule'  //maybe delete the same page of app.module.ts
          },
        ]
```

then also you need to add `path: '', component: yourcomponent` in your `FriendDetailsPageModule` routing

Answer (score 0):

You mention that:

> The friend-details folder is in the friend folder, so the path should actually work.

Are you being accurate with your words? If so the path should be:

```
../friend/friend-details/friend-details.module#FriendDetailsPageModule
```